# OWIN authentication server and shared cookies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, owin

I have an OWIN architecture in place with the following structure:
[image]

So first step the User login inside my MVC application using the following code:

```
var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + $scope.loginModel.Username + "&password=" + $scope.loginModel.Password;

$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: identityApi + 'Token',
        data: data,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.isLogged = true;
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem("token", data.access_token);
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.isLogged = false;
        $scope.queryError = data || 'An error occurred' + ' Status ' + status;
    });
```

At this point I can call any **[Authorize]** Controller on my Web API and it succeed. The problem is inside my MVC application.
After I login, I cannot find in the cookies the authentication cookie generated by my custom **OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider** so inside my MVC application, when I check:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

I always get back *null* while if I check this on my Data Controller (*the one that receives the token id*) I can extrapolate the Claim.

This is how I grant access by the /Token endpoint:
    // verify the credentials
    var userManager = new UserManager(new CustomUsersStorage());

```
CustomUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

if (user == null)
{
    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
    return;
}
// generate the Token identity
ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
// generate the Coockie identity    
ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
// validate the token and the request
AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
context.Validated(ticket);
// signIn with the Cookie
context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, cookiesIdentity);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to accomplish the same thing you are describing, did you ever come across a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, actually is all about how you set the Cookie option in OWIN, if you set Passive Mode then the Current Identity won't be populated while if you set it to Active it will and every request passing a Bearer Token will be populated with the Identity embed in the Token. Read here for more info:
http://brockallen.com/2013/10/27/host-authentication-and-web-api-with-owin-and-active-vs-passive-authentication-middleware/